# Javascript, why have to "new Function()"?

Tags: javascript

These codes work well.

```
<input id="mainCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
...
var controlCheckbox = document.getElementById( "mainCheckbox" ),
...
controlCheckbox["onclick"] = new Function( "controlCheckbox.Notify(controlCheckbox.checked)" );
```

Why this cannot work?

```
controlCheckbox["onclick"] = controlCheckbox.Notify(controlCheckbox.checked);
```

Comment: That second code won't work because it's behavior is completely different that the first.  You should gain a better understanding of what operator new really does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work because it doesn't assign a function, but instead calls `.Notify` immediately.

You can however use anonymous function syntax to create the function.

```
controlCheckbox["onclick"] = function() {
    controlCheckbox.Notify(controlCheckbox.checked);
};
```

This would be a more common approach than using the `Function` constructor.

One difference between the two approaches is that functions created from `new Function` will not be able to use an enclosing local variable scope. It will be as though it was created directly in the `global` scope.

```
;(function() {
    var foo = "bar"; // local variable

    var x = new Function("console.log(foo);");

    x(); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
})();
```

So unless the variable in your first code example is in the `global` scope, it won't work because the `controlCheckbox` variable will not be accessible.

Although, because the variable is simply a reference to the element being bound, you don't really need it, since you can use `this` in the handler.

```
controlCheckbox["onclick"] = new Function("this.Notify(this.checked)" );
```